# Regex to split a string into args without breaking the quoted text

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string, split

I want to take all words from a string and convert them into an array, but i don't want to break sentences that are enclosed in quotes

My code:

```js
const content = 'this is a simple text that i "need to split into" arguments'
const args = content.split(/ +/g)
console.log(args)

// Result: ['this', 'is', 'a', 'simple', 'text', 'that', 'i', '"need', 'to', 'split', 'into"', 'arguments']
```

What do I need as a result:

```
// Result: ['this', 'is', 'a', 'simple', 'text', 'that', 'i', 'need to split into', 'arguments']
```

Comment: Will it contain only single string with `" "` in whole string?

Comment: @decpk no, can contain many

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple approach would be to use string `match()` along with the regex pattern `".*?"|\w+`.  This pattern will eagerly first try to find a next doubly-quoted term.  That failing, it will search for a single word.  This approach avoids the possibility of consuming words which appear inside double quotes.

```js
var content = 'this is a simple text that i "need to split into" arguments';
var matches = content.match(/".*?"|\w+/g);
for (var i=0; i < matches.length; ++i) {
    matches[i] = matches[i].replace(/^"(.*)"$/, "$1");
}
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: its possible for me to ignore it if the quotes have a backslash before?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are no escaped quotes, and the quotes are correctly paired up.

```js
const content = 'this is a simple text that i "need to split into" arguments'
args = content.split(/\s(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/g);
console.log(args);
```